# Creating a New User Account

Tags: c#, beginner, .net, authentication

I feel like this maybe to much for one method...  This method lives inside of a service class which is called by an interface. It dumps data into three different tables within a database.

```
public UserAccount CreateAccount(NewAccount newAccount)
{
  if (!AccountAlreadyExists(newAccount.UserName))
  {
    string salt = StringCipher.GenerateCypher();
    UserAccount account = new UserAccount()
    {
      UserId = newAccount.UserName,
      PasswordHash = CreatePasswordHash(newAccount.Password),
      Lock = true,
      Created = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    User user = new User()
    {
      UserId = newAccount.UserName
    };
    UserContact contact = new UserContact() 
    {
      ContactTypeId = ContactType.EmailPrimary,
      Contact = StringCipher.Encrypt(newAccount.UserEmail, salt),
      UserId = account.UserId,
      Active = true,
      Created = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return account;
  }
  return null;
}
```

any suggestions on how to slim this down or streamline?

Comment: Why is there a class `NewAccount` and also a class `UserAccount`? I think you should remove `NewAccount` and use `UserAccount` instead. you then can save almost the whole block after creating a new `UserAccount` and rather have it passed into the method (dependency injection). Also make your `AccountAlreadyExists` method accept a `UserAccount` as argument and not a `UserName`(String?) or rename it to `UserNameAlreadyExists`.

Comment: Already scratched the NewAccount class and am just using the view model that calls the interface for all this to begin with.

Comment: It might be a personal preference, but you have a bit `if` block, then the else is a return null, you might switch that up to be `if (AccountAlreadyExists(newAccount.UserName)) return null;` then have the rest of your code without the nested braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think this is fine if the concept of creating a `UserContact`, `User` is directly tied to creating a `UserAccount`, i.e. one cannot live without the other.

That is because the abstraction of the method CreateAccount() hides away the implementation details of what needs to be done (insertion of data into 3 tables).

As you already have this abstraction you are now in the postion to potentially refactor the CreateAccount without effecting the rest of your code. Excellant!

So, as an option, I might consider refactoring the service layer itself so that the CreateAccount() method is a bit more *streamlined*, as you put it.

```
public UserAccount CreateAccount(NewAccount newAccount)
{
  if (!AccountAlreadyExists(newAccount.UserName))
  {
    UserAccount account = CreateUserAccount(newAccount);    
    User user = CreateUser(newAccount); 
    UserContact contact = CreateContact(newAccount);

    db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;

    db.SaveChanges();

    return account;
  }

  return null;
}

private UserAccount CreateUserAccount(NewAccount newAccount)
{
    string salt = StringCipher.GenerateCypher();

    return new UserAccount()
    {
      UserId = newAccount.UserName,
      PasswordHash = CreatePasswordHash(newAccount.Password),
      Lock = true,
      Created = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
}

private User CreateUser(NewAccount newAccount)
{
    return new User()
    {
      UserId = newAccount.UserName
    };
}

private UserContact CreateContact(NewAccount newAccount)
{
    return new UserContact() 
    {
      ContactTypeId = ContactType.EmailPrimary,
      Contact = StringCipher.Encrypt(newAccount.UserEmail, salt),
      UserId = newAccount.UserName,
      Active = true,
      Created = DateTime.UtcNow
    }
}
```

This first lot of refactoring lead me to realise that `newAccount` is passed to each of the 3 methods.  I thought at this stage perhaps a class for these actions might make sense so that the common parameter is extracted to a class level variable.

```
public UserAccount CreateAccount(NewAccount newAccount)
{
  if (!AccountAlreadyExists(newAccount.UserName))
  {
    var accountBuilder = new AccountBuilder(newAccount);
    Account account = accountBuilder.CreateAccount();   

    db.Entry(account.UserAccount).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.Entry(account.Contact).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.Entry(account.User).State = EntityState.Added;

    db.SaveChanges();

    return account;
  }

  return null;
}

internal class UserAccountBuilder
{
    private readonly NewAccount _newAccount;

    public UserAccountBuilder(NewAccount account)
    {
        _newAccount = account;
    }

    public Account CreateAccount() 
    {
        return  new Account(
            CreateUserAccount(),
            CreateUser(),
            CreateUserContact()
        );
    }

    private string GetUsername()
    {
        return _newAccount.UserName;
    }

    private UserAccount CreateUserAccount()
    {
        string salt = StringCipher.GenerateCypher();

        return new UserAccount()
        {
          UserId = GetUsername(),
          PasswordHash = CreatePasswordHash(_newAccount.Password),
          Lock = true,
          Created = DateTime.UtcNow
        };
    }

    private User CreateUser()
    {
        return new User()
        {
          UserId = GetUsername()
        };
    }

    private UserContact CreateContact()
    {
        return new UserContact() 
        {
          ContactTypeId = ContactType.EmailPrimary,
          Contact = StringCipher.Encrypt(_newAccount.UserEmail, salt),
          UserId = GetUserName(),
          Active = true,
          Created = DateTime.UtcNow
        }
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public UserAccount Account { get; private set; }
    public User User { get; private set; }
    public UserContact Contact { get; private set; }

    public Account(
        UserAccount userAccount,
        User user,
        UserContact userContact)
    {
        Account = userAccount;
        User = user;
        Contact = userContact;
    }
}
```

> NOTE:  This might be overkill but what I was going for here was
>   extracting the persistance criteria out from the creation of the
>   account itself.  Hence you could use this class to unit test creation
>   of accounts without mocking or worrying about the db persistance layer
>   which is contained in the service class layer.

Comment: What do you think of this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56241/user-authentication-bundle